# Zalenium idleTimeout property use?

Tags: zalenium

Does Zalenium idleTimeout property means that the container would be alive for the configured timeout period.
If I set capabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout",120);
Does this mean, that Zalenium would identify the container as 'Zalenium Test Completed' after 120 secs.

So, if my testcase is a lengthy one which spans beyond 120 secs, does Zalenium allow the testcase to proceed further or will it shutdown the container.

This is what I observed while executing lengthy testcases using Zalenium.
Can somebody please help me with a response to this query?

Answer (score 1):

`idleTimeout` is the length of time a session can stay alive without receiving new commands. It is not related to the total length of the test.

Comment: :Thanks for the response. So, does that mean that if the configured idleTimeout = 45sec. My testcase execution takes longer than 45sec in a container, Zalenium would not automatically shutdown the container after 45sec.

Comment: Yes, the test could be longer than 45 seconds and the container won't shut down. But a command must be sent before those 45 seconds pass.